# Execute query string and get result with varying number of columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to transform a list of correlation values into a correlation matrix.
**But I can't get the result after executing a string query.**

The list/table(named corrtemp) is like this:

```
| name | colname | value |
| ---- | ------- | ----- |
| a    | a       | 1     |
| a    | b       | 0.5   |
| a    | c       | 0.3   |
| b    | a       | 0.5   |
| b    | b       | 1     |
| b    | c       | 0.2   |
| c    | a       | 0.3   |
| c    | b       | 0.2   |
| c    | c       | 1     |
```

The output should be like this:

```
| name |  a  |  b  |  c  |
| ---- |-----| --- | --- |
| a    |  1  | 0.5 | 0.3 |
| b    | 0.5 |  1  | 0.2 |
| c    | 0.3 | 0.2 |  1  |
```

The number of distinct names is unknown. So I loop to generate a string query. I want to execute it and get the query result in the result console. Currently, my code is like this:

```
do $$
declare 
    i integer := 0;
     sql0 varchar := 'SELECT DISTINCT temp0.name, cor0.value AS '||(SELECT DISTINCT name FROM corrtemp LIMIT 1)||' FROM corrtemp AS temp0'||chr(13);
     sql1 varchar := 'left JOIN corrtemp AS cor0 ON cor0.colname = temp0.name AND cor0.name = ''a'''||chr(13);
     sql2 varchar := 'WITH temp';
     sql4 varchar;
begin
    sql4 := sql0 || sql1 ||chr(13);
    i := i + 1;
    while i < (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) FROM corrtemp) loop
        sql4 := chr(13)|| 
                sql2|| 
                CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) || 
                ' AS('||
                chr(13)||
                sql4||
                ')' ||
                'SELECT temp'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) || '.*, cor'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) ||'.value AS '||(SELECT DISTINCT name FROM corrtemp LIMIT 1 OFFSET i)||' FROM  temp'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5))||chr(13)||
                'left JOIN corrtemp AS cor'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) ||  ' ON cor'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) || '.colname = temp'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) || '.name AND cor'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) || '.name = '''|| (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM corrtemp LIMIT 1 OFFSET i)||''''||chr(13);
        i := i + 1;
        end loop;
end$$
```

I tried `EXECUTE sql4`  inside the `do` and it only returns an 'OK' in the information console.

I need the query result to display in the result console just like after simply running `SELECT * FROM corrtemp`.

Comment: I am thinking using `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION corrsql() RETURNS TABLE`, but I cannot decide the cols of the table.

Comment: Like has been commented, SQL demands to know the return type at execution time. The result type cannot be completely dynamic. Maybe you know the ***maximum*** of possible distinct names and that's a reasonable number?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes, I am able to know the number of the distinct names. The names and the number of names change should be allowed to change every time I call the function.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating function. It doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION list2matrix() RETURNS setof record LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
declare 
   i integer := 0;
  sql0 varchar := 'SELECT DISTINCT temp0.name, cor0.value AS '||(SELECT DISTINCT name FROM corrtemp LIMIT 1)||' FROM corrtemp AS temp0'||chr(13);
  sql1 varchar := 'left JOIN corrtemp AS cor'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) ||  ' ON cor'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) || '.colname = temp'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) || '.name AND cor'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) || '.name = '''|| (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM corrtemp LIMIT 1 OFFSET i)||''''||chr(13);
  sql2 varchar := 'WITH temp';
  sql3 varchar := 'SELECT temp'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) || '.*, cor'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) ||'.value AS '||(SELECT DISTINCT name FROM corrtemp LIMIT 1 OFFSET i)||' FROM  temp'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5))||chr(13) ;
  sql4 varchar;
begin
   sql4 := sql0 || sql1 ||chr(13);
  i := i + 1;
   while i < (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) FROM corrtemp) loop
      sql4 := chr(13)|| 
            sql2|| 
        CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) || 
        ' AS('||
        chr(13)||
        sql4||
        ')' ||
        'SELECT temp'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) || '.*, cor'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) ||'.value AS '||(SELECT DISTINCT name FROM corrtemp LIMIT 1 OFFSET i)||' FROM  temp'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5))||chr(13)||
        'left JOIN corrtemp AS cor'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) ||  ' ON cor'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) || '.colname = temp'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) || '.name AND cor'|| CAST(i AS VARCHAR(5)) || '.name = '''|| (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM corrtemp LIMIT 1 OFFSET i)||''''||chr(13);
    i := i + 1;
     end loop;
         RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql4;
end$$;

select list2matrix();
```

It sends the following error message to me:

*ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set*

It seems like I still have to define the table structure, which I really can't because the correlation matrix always changes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `DO` statement hasn't any input/output possibilities. You can change data inside `DO` statement, but you cannot to use `DO` statement to get any result.

Comment: Ｉtried create function returns sth (table/setof record). The problem I am facing right now is that I cannot decide the column name and column type. Both ways need this information to show the result table.

Comment: You cannot to use functions for crosstabing too, because the structure of result must be known before execution. There is trick with cursors - http://okbob.blogspot.com/2008/08/using-cursors-for-generating-cross.html or if you use `psql` client, then you can use `\crosstabview` command.

Comment: Here is the reality I am facing:
1, Due to technical limitations, I need a query that can directly output the correlation table.
2, I an unable to know the number of cols and the colnames, that's why I wrote a while loop to create the query string for whatever the correlation list I have.

I read through your blog. It's stunning. But It still need to specify the col names of the output table, right?

Comment: @sh12121212: there is no way you can run a SQL statement without making the number, name and data type of each column known to the server **before** the query is actually run. You could aggregate the "dynamic part" into a JSON column though if your frontend can handle that https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/pivot-alternatives/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried json, and got stuck when the function, `json_populate_recordset` asked me to define the table structure.  ;-)